# In Java how do you randomly select a letter (a-z)?

Tags: java, random

If I want to randomly select a letter between a and z, I assume I have to use the `Random` class:

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

But since this only generates numbers, what do I need to do to apply this to letters?

Answer (score 26):

```
Random r = new Random();
char c = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
```

Comment: For other character ranges, see http://www.asciitable.com/, then http://www.unicode.org/charts/

Answer (score 5):

Letters, or more exactly, characters, are numbers (from 0 to 255 in extended ascii, 0 to 127 in non-extended). For instance, in ASCII, 'A' (quote means character, as opposed to string) is 65. So 1 + 'A' would give you 66 - 'B'. 
So, you can take a random number from 0 to 26, add it to the character 'a', and here you are : random letter.

You could also do it with a string, typing "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" and taking a random position in this chain, but Barker solution is more elegant.

Comment: I think the "pick a random character of a given string" is the more elegant solution.

Answer (score 3):

alter version of @Michael Barker

```
Random r = new Random();
int c = r.nextInt(26) + (byte)'a';
System.out.println((char)c);
```

Comment: Why the cast to `byte`?

Answer (score 2):

```
char randomLetter = (char) ('a' + Math.random() * ('z'-'a' + 1));
```

Answer (score 2):

why assume to use Random instead of Math.random? You can even make the code shorter...

```
public static char genChar(){
    return (char)(Math.random()*26 + 'a');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomStringUtils.randomAlphabetic;
...
randomAlphabetic(1).toLowerCase()
```

this gives you a string with single character

Answer (score 1):

To randomly select a letter from (a- z) I would do the following:

```
Random rand = new Random();
...
char c = rand.nextInt(26) + 'a';
```

Since **Random.nextInt()** generates a value from 0 to 25, you need only add an offset of **'a'** to produce the lowercase letters.

Answer (score 0):

use the ascii value of the letters to generate the random number.

Answer (score 0):

```
Random r = new Random();
char symbel = (char)(r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
if(symbel>='a' && symbel <= 'z') {
    System.out.println("Small Letter" + symbel);
} else {
    System.out.println("Not a letter" + symbel);
}
```

Comment: why checking if the char is outside the `a`-`z` range? That can never happen.