# How to randomly select 7 letters(a to z ) in java

Tags: java, random

I want to select 7 random letters from a to z

so far i have found only ways to select a single letter https://stackoverflow.com/a/5202888/3209901

```
Random r = new Random();
char c = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
```

Why seven letters because , i need to apply some conditions to those 7 letters  -  to check the words formed by those seven letters , the word length should be minimum of 4 letters ......

Comment: what char `c = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');` will generate 1st char .`char c1 = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');`  will generate 2nd char ..do 7 time to get seven letters

Comment: If you can generate one letter, why not just do that 7 times? Or do you require them all be different. In that case, a popular algorithm is to generate a set of all 26 possible letters from the alphabet, then shuffle it and pick the first 7 elements.

Comment: i need 7 letters coz , i need to make some conditions like how many words can be formed with those 7 letters , length of those words.....

Comment: ya @hermit  i need something like that , thanks

Comment: There is no need to "promote" a solution in comments. imagine if we all did that ?!?

Comment: I was just helping him

Answer (score 3):

Here's Java-8 solution:

```
new Random().ints('a', 'z'+1).distinct()
            .limit(7).forEach(ch -> System.out.println((char)ch));
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
Random rnd = new Random();
final String AB = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"; 
StringBuilder alphabat = new StringBuilder();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
   alphabat.append(AB.charAt(rnd.nextInt(AB.length())));
}
System.out.println(alphabat.toString());
```

Comment: am I mistaken or this will generate only 4 random letters?

Comment: this will give you a word with 4 random letters from A to Z

Comment: @sharonbn It will generate 4 random letters. Change terminator to 7 and it will make 7.

Comment: I know that. I was just wondering, OP asked for 7 letters, why not give him/her the correct answer..

Answer (score 0):

This solution requires no loops and no Random generators. It produces a `List<String>` with 7 random letters

```
    String[] abArr = {"A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z"};
    List<String> abList = Arrays.asList(abArr);
    Collections.shuffle(abList);
    System.out.println(abList.subList(0, 7));
```

Comment: Why no random generators? Have you looked inside [`Collections.shuffle`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Collections.java#Collections.shuffle%28java.util.List%29)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Set` as it does not store any duplicate elements and thus is easier to implement.

```
 Random r = new Random();
 Set <Character>mySet=new <Character>HashSet();
 while(mySet.size()!=7){
 char c = (char) (r.nextInt(26) + 'a');
 mySet.add(c);
 }

 for(char c:mySet){
     System.out.print(c+" ");
 }
```

`Output:a q d g i j m`

Answer (score 0):

Now, depending on what you ultimately want to achieve, you could simply do something like...

```
Random rnd = new Random();
for (int index = 0; index < 7; index++) {
    System.out.println((char)(rnd.nextInt(26) + 'a'));
}
```

Which will just generate 7 random characters.  You could add these to an array, `List` or `StringBuilder`.  You also could use `rnd.nextInt(3) + 4)` to generate a random word length.

Now, if you didn't want duplicate values, you could use a `Set`, something like...

```
Random rnd = new Random();
Set<Character> characters = new HashSet<>();
while (characters.size() < 7) {
    characters.add((char)(rnd.nextInt(26) + 'a'));
}

for (Character value : characters) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

Which will keep looping until the `Set` contains the required number of characters (in this `7`, but see the previous comment to generate a random length)

You could also do something like...

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".split("")));
Collections.shuffle(values);
List<String> randomValues = values.subList(0, 7);
for (String value : randomValues) {
    System.out.println(value);
}
```

which would make more sense if the character list was been generated from another source, but demonstrates the `Collections.shuffle` method