# I have a string "I love stack overflow very much" how to remove spaces between character and make groups of 8 character?

Tags: java, arrays, string, sorting

I have a string `"I love stack overflow very much"` how to remove spaces between character and make groups of 8 character? how to add dummy data if no of character does not divided by 8 to make group of 8?how to add dummy data to make groups of 8 characrers?

Comment: How far have you tried? To generate a random char, you can reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202866/in-java-how-do-you-randomly-select-a-letter-a-z

Comment: Before your question gets closed, please show us what actual output you want, and also any code you have tried.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String string = "I love stack overflow very much";

        //replacing all newline and and then making tokens
        String[] words = string.replaceAll("\\s", "").split("(?<=\\G.{8})");

        for (String st : words) {
            if (st.length() == 8) { // if length of the string is 8, just print the string
                System.out.println(st);
            } else {
                System.out.print(st);

                // printing dummy characters after the final string
                for (int i = 0; i < 8 - st.length(); i++) {
                    System.out.print("X"); // assuming dummy character = X;
                }
            }
        }

        System.out.println("\n");

        // Reverse
        for (String st : words) {
            if (st.length() == 8) {
                System.out.println(new StringBuilder(st).reverse().toString());
            } else {
                String revString = st;
                for (int i = 0; i < 8 - st.length(); i++) {
                    revString += "X";
                }
                System.out.println(new StringBuilder(revString).reverse().toString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Ilovesta
ckoverfl
owverymu
chXXXXXX

atsevolI
lfrevokc
umyrevwo
XXXXXXhc
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now! Please edit your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: @Makyen thanks for the tips. I have edited my answer.

Comment: You shouldn't just give the answer like this. The poster of the question appears to be trying to figure out his homework. Can you re-edit to not include the details of the answer? Thanks!

Comment: hey Rimon Mostafiz thank you

Comment: In the end how to reverse print every group? Rimon Mostafiz

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7569335/reverse-a-string-in-java

Comment: I need this output
otsevolI
flrevokc
umyrevwo
xxxxxxhc

Answer (score -1):

Here is a one-liner solution using a regex which you can try:

```
String input = "I love stack overflow very much";
String[] parts = input.replaceAll("\\s", "").split("(?<=\\G.{8})");
String dummy = "X";  // or whatever placeholder you want
parts[parts.length-1] += new String(new char[8 - parts[parts.length-1].length()]).replace("\0", dummy);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
```

This solution pads the final term in the array on the right with Xs, should the final term have less than 8 characters.

**Output:**

```
[Ilovesta, ckoverfl, owverymu, chXXXXXX]
```

Comment: This answer meets the specs of the original problem AFAIK.

Comment: It does NOT satisfy *all* of the requirements: "*add dummy data if no of character does not divided by 8*"

Comment: @RemyLebeau I updated my answer to add right padding to the final string, should that be necessary.

Comment: thank you Tim Biegeleisen so now how to reverse print every group?

Comment: @HamzaMasood Just reverse the input string, that's all.

Comment: in your output last one is 'ch' but i want that group exactly 8 character using dummy data

Comment: @HamzaMasood No, it _is_ 8 characters, I padded it to the right with spaces.

Comment: yes you are right my mistake

Comment: please explain the 3rd line of your code

Comment: The third line pads the last array entry to the right with spaces.

Comment: can i replace spaces with 'X'

Comment: you said reverse your input but out put is this 
[ch     , owverymu,ckoverfl, Ilovesta ]

I need this 
[[atsevoll, lfrevokc, umyrevwo,      hc ]

Comment: @sgd You have showed zero effort or gratitude for my time.  I won't help you anymore, sorry.

Comment: just said you dont know